# Use WHERE clause with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to use where clause when there are more than one JOIN and WHERE clause needs to be applied on only one of them(last join). I have used where clause below which will be applied only to Second join but it does not seems right the way I am doing it, any suggestions?

```
 SELECT A.Name
      , B.Address
      , B.City
      , C.Position
      , C.Salary
      , D.WorkTime as Time
   From Employee as A 
   Left Join EmployeeAddressInfo as B
     on A.EID = B.AddId
   Left Join EmployeeRoleInfo as C
     on A.EID = C.RoleID
   Left Join EmployeeTime as D
     on A.EID = D.TimeID
  where Position='Engineer'
```

Comment: What WHERE clause do you want to use?

Comment: "Position" Column is also belongs to the table EmployeeTime from that table I want to select the Worktime only for the value "Engineer"

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause is turning the outer joins into inner joins.  You need to move it to the appropriate `on` clause.  For instance, if `Position` is in `EmployeeTime`:

```
From Employee A Left Join
     EmployeeAddressInfo B
     on A.EID = B.AddId Left Join
     EmployeeRoleInfo C
     on A.EID = C.RoleID Left Join
     EmployeeTime D
     on A.EID = D.TimeID and D.Position = 'Engineer'
```

I would also strongly advise you to use *abbreviations* for table aliases rather than meaningless characters.  For instance:

```
From Employee e Left Join
     EmployeeAddressInfo eai
     on e.EID = eai.AddId Left Join
     EmployeeRoleInfo er
     on e.EID = er.RoleID Left Join
     EmployeeTime et
     on e.EID = et.TimeID and et.Position = 'Engineer'
```

Comment: As I added  and et.Position = 'Engineer'  in the query values from TABLE C comes NUll....without and et.Position = 'Engineer'  I can get all the values from Table C

Comment: @Jr.Developer . . . If this works, is there a reason why you unaccepted the answer and chose another posted 8 hours later that appears to be incorrect (the column is taken from the wrong table)?  As the OP, you can accept whichever answer you like, but this seems curious.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.Name
      , B.Address
      , B.City
      , C.Position
      , C.Salary
      , D.WorkTime as Time
   From Employee as A 
   Left Join EmployeeAddressInfo as B
     on A.EID = B.AddId
   Left Join EmployeeRoleInfo as C
     on A.EID = C.RoleID and C.Position='Engineer'
   Left Join EmployeeTime as D
     on A.EID = D.TimeID
```

Comment: According to the OP's comments, this answer is incorrect.  It is very curious that the OP accepted it.